# pyqt5のQListViewで現在のIndexを指定したい

Tags: python, pyqt5

Pyqt5のQListViewを使って作ったアイテムモデルで現在のインデックスを指定したいです。

index0ボタンを押したら現在指定されているインデックスが0番目になるようにしたいのですが、やり方が分かりません。

どうすればよいのでしょうか。

---

**表示されるGUI**
[image: 画像]

**ソースコード**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.__init__(self)
        #self.nodes = ['node0', 'node1', 'node2', "node4", "node5"]

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        return self.createIndex(row, column, nodes[row])

    def parent(self, index):
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, index):
        if index.internalPointer() in nodes:
            return 0
        return len(nodes)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == 0: 
            return index.internalPointer()
        else:
            return None

    def supportedDropActions(self): 
        return QtCore.Qt.CopyAction | QtCore.Qt.MoveAction         

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | \
               QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled        

    def mimeTypes(self):
        return ['text/xml']

    def mimeData(self, indexes):
        mimedata = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimedata.setData('text/xml', 'mimeData')
        return mimedata

    def dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, column, parent):
        print ('dropMimeData %s %s %s %s' % (data.data('text/xml'), action, row, parent))
        return True


class MainForm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

        self.treeModel = TreeModel()
        
        self.view = QListView()
        self.view.setModel(self.treeModel)
        self.view.activated.connect(self.viewClicked2)#ダブルクリックでの動作
        self.view.clicked.connect(self.viewClicked)
        
        self.btn=QPushButton("index0")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.change_index)
        
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.show()
        
    def viewClicked(self, indexClicked):
        print('index of proxy row', indexClicked.row())
        
    def viewClicked2(self, index):
        print(index.row())
        
    def change_index(self):
        #print(self.view.currentIndex())
        #self.view.setCurrentIndex(0)
        pass


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nodes=['node0', 'node1', 'node2', "node4", "node5"]
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記のコードで最初の行を[`select`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#select)できます。
[`createIndex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#createIndex)の第一引数で選択行を変更できます。

```
def change_index(self):
    index = self.view.model().createIndex(0, 0)
    self.view.selectionModel().select(index, QItemSelectionModel.ClearAndSelect)
```

[SO本家の類似質問(C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/461870/8248751)